# Why my code doesn't work if i don't put case 0 in switch

Tags: c, switch-statement

I was  finding the greatest number using switch case in c. Here if I start the switch with case 0 the program executes perfectly.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

  int main()
     {
     int a,b;
     scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);


     switch(a>b)
     {
     case 0:
        printf("%d is maximum",b);
        break;
     case 1:
        printf("%d is maximum",a);
        break;
     }


    return 0;
```

But when I use case 1 instead of case 2.The program takes the input but doesn't show any result. What's the reason?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
     int a,b;
     scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);


     switch(a>b)
     {
     case 1:
        printf("%d is maximum",b);
        break;
     case 2:
        printf("%d is maximum",a);
        break;
     }


    return 0;
```

Comment: Your second code block won't compile - you cannot have duplicate `case` lines. (Is it a typo?)

Comment: oh sorry my mistake

Comment: it's 
case 1:

case 2:

Comment: Try `printf("%d", a>b);` before the switch to understand what is going on

Comment: @EdHeal should i use it on both of the cases

Comment: No. Before the switch

Comment: Better to use if than switch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comparison `a>b` is an expression that will evaluate to either *true* or *false*. When representing (or testing) these "Boolean" values in `C`, *false* is equivalent to ***zero*** and *true* is equivalent to ***one***.

So, the `switch` statement in your first code block will do as you expect. However, in your second block, the tested expression can ***never*** have the value `2` so, if `a` *is not greater* than `b`, nothing will be printed! (However, if `a` *is* larger than `b`, then the `case 1:` block will run.)

PS: If the evaluation of the expression in the brackets following the `switch` does not match *any* of the given `case`s inside the `switch (...) {}` block, then your code will silently ignore that block … ***unless*** you add a `default:` block (traditionally added at the end, but it can go anywhere a `case X:` could). Maybe you could try this to see for yourself.

Comment: So whenever I will compare between 2 values I have to express it with 0 and 1?

Comment: @MustabirApurbo In many cases, you can just use the implied Boolean result of the comparison, such as: `if (a<b) /* do something */; else /* do something else */;`

Answer (score 1):

For starters in one switch statement there may not two identical case labels. SO this code should not compile

```
 switch(a>b)
 {
 case 1:
    printf("%d is maximum",b);
    break;
 case 1:
    printf("%d is maximum",a);
    break;
 }
```

From the C Standard (6.8.4.2 The switch statement)

> 3 The expression of each case label shall be an integer constant
>   expression and no two of the case constant expressions in the same
>   switch statement shall have the same value after conversion. ...

In C the value of a logical expression (as for example, `a > b` ) can be either integer 0 (false) or integer 1 (true). So the case labels in this switch statement are correct

```
 switch(a>b)
 {
 case 0:
    printf("%d is maximum",b);
    break;
 case 1:
    printf("%d is maximum",a);
    break;
 }
```